Could not determine the dependencies of task ':camera_android_camerax:test'
What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':camera_android_camerax:test'.

Could not create task ':camera_android_camerax:testDebugUnitTest'.
this and base files have different roots: D:\Castro\Bureau\proyecto flutter my primary app\flutter camera\flutter_camera\build\camera_android_camerax and C:\Users\ysmac\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\camera_android_camerax-0.6.7+2\android.

I've already checked the whole file but I don't know what I could do in that case, anyone knows? I would appreciate your help
